# Paste multi-line string into GVIM at cursor position

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

When I copy a **two-line** text from (e.g.) a PDF opened in Acrobat Reader into gvim using CTRL-V, the text is inserted **above** the line in gvim where I was positioned, instead of **at the position where my cursor is**. (scenario: I want to copy a document title that is spread over two lines and paste it in between a html tag in gvim).

If I do the same with a single-line of text, the text is correctly pasted at the cursor's position.

What should I do to make it also work with two-lines of text (e.g. something like 'paste without formatting')?

Important: the string to be pasted consists of two lines separated by a carriage return (or something similar)!

**Solution**

There are actually two valid solutions:

- using CTRL-R * to paste at the cursors position (and keeping the clipboard content multi-lined)
- do a remapping of the paste command to replace all carriage returns in the clipboard string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all it seems CTRL-V is mapped to something because normally pasting in VIM is not done using CTRL-V (CTRL-V is visual block).

Second the behaviour you are seeing is standard vi[m] behaviour, if you yank one or more entire lines, pasting will always result in one or more lines above or below the current line.

I do not know of any builtin way to achieve what you are trying to do. But you could always remap CTRL-V to something that does do what you want, i.e.

```
:map <C-V> i<CR><Esc>"*P
```

After that pasting multiple lines will be between the characters your cursor was at, but this remapping probably is not what you want in other cases.

**EDIT**

OK, I found another way.

When in insert mode, type

```
CTRL-R *
```

this will paste the contents of the clipboard buffer at the location the cursor is at. (You can also use this to paste the contents of other buffers)

Comment: Ah, finally somebody who understood my problem :-) 
I see what you are trying to do, and it is indeed only a half-working workaround. Strange that vim can't handle this properly. Isn't there a way to remove carriage returns in the buffer (clipboard) before pasting it into VIM?
(BTW: the non-standard ctrl-v shortcut isn't the problem here)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strip newlines from a register before pasting from it, you can use the expression register `"=`:

```
:map <C-v> "=substitute(@*, "\n", " ", "g")<CR>p
```

Comment: Very nice tip. It took me some experimenting to realize this only works when NOT in insert mode. But I can use :imap to map it there as well. Thanks!

Comment: Small update: I've altered you're solution by using P instead of p at the end of the mapping command. This pastes it after the cursor, which feels more natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the shortcuts `p` and `P` (paste after and before the cursor, respectively). Add `"*` to specify contents of the system register (Windows clipboard, in your case), or `"+` (for UNIX).

So, you can use:

- `"*p` paste before cursor
- `"*P` paste after cursor
- `"*y` copy (visual area, or takes a
  postfix telling Vim "what" to copy)
- `"*d` cut (visual area, or with a
  postfix)

and so forth.

Comment: p and P pastes from the VIM buffer, not from the Windows clipboard, so that doesn't work in this case

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the tip, but that still doesn't work. It gets pasted ABOVE the line where I am positioned, instead of at the cursors position

Answer (score 1):

```
:set paste
```

before you paste something into the buffer

```
:set nopaste
```

to restore formatting settings

Comment: nice try, but doesn't work for me. The 2 lines still get pasted ABOVE the current line

Answer (score 0):

To paste into gVim from the windows clipboard at the position of the cursor use

```
"+gP
```

Don't forget the double quote.

Comment: The question was not how to paste, but how to paste at the cursor given the clipboard content contains two lines (separated by a carriage return)

Comment: I believe I understood your question. Are you saying that you tried "+gP and it didn't work? It does for me.

Comment: I've updated my response so that it is directly answering your question.